# Debugging PHP files on browser with Eclipse and xDebug

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

I have been reading online about debugging with PHP for Developers on Eclipse and xDebug.
I have installed all the necessary files for xDebug, and now when I am in Eclipse I can run the debugger with a script and it works just fine.

The issue is that i am using AppServ (Apache, PHP and MySQL) on my Windows machine, and what I would like to do is to debug my PHP files in Eclipse when I am loading the PHP pages in my browser (instead of running them as scripts in Eclipse).

Is that possible?

Joel

Answer (score 14):

In Eclipse, go to 'Preferences' then 'PHP' 'Debug' 'Installed Debuggers', 'XDebug', then 'Configure'

[image: In Eclipse, go to 'Preferences' then 'PHP' 'Debug' 'Installed Debuggers', 'XDebug', then 'Configure']

For 'Accept remote session' change this to 'localhost'

This will tell XDebug in Eclipse to debug whenever anyone connects with xdebug cookies or URL params set - using this with [Easy Xdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/) or [xDebug Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) then makes debugging from realistic in-browser contexts a doddle.

I'm assuming you have Eclipse PDT for this, I'm not sure if the steps are different otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you ask for, but you can take a look and decide.

Easy Xdebug with Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/

Answer (score 0):

Here at Oodles Technologies, we work with PHP on an extensive basis and hope this answer helps.

After opening your the php.ini file, add the following lines:

***Note :*** (php.ini file contains in both the folders that is apache and php, it is advisable to configure the file which is present in apache folder)

```
<span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll"(use zend_extension_ts as variable name if you are using php version below 5.3)
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
</span></span>
```

After this, Make sure that "c:/wamp/tmp" exist in file system, if not then create that directory.

Then Restart your apache services.

Lastly, open your NetBeans or eclipse IDE and configure xdebug in settings.

I hope you find it useful.